# Unable to use datetime2(0) in Partition Function

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a large table that I want to partition by a `datetime2(0)` column. AFAIK, `datetime2(0)` is stored as `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'`. However, I can't create the partition function with the same format.

```
Use PartitionLogTest
Go
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfRequestTimeRange (DATETIME2(0))
AS
RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (NULL,
                        '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 
                        '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
                        '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
                        '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Error message:

```
Could not implicitly convert range values type specified at ordinal 1 to partition function parameter type.
```

I've tried formats like `'20150101000000'` or `'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'` but still couldn't make it work. Is there a correct format or I can't/shouldn't create partition function with `datetime2(0)`?

Comment: You should explicitly use `CONVERT()` with a specific date format rather than relying on implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the NULL as the first partition value should get you past the error.
(**UPDATE** - Read the comments further down from Dan's post - he actually DOES recommend the action of the OP - you just need to use convert(datetime2(0),null)

Also - check out Dan Guzman's [Table Partitioning Best Practices](http://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/).

Well - after re-reading Dan's post, he actually DOES recommend creating the first partition with a NULL boundary for RANGE RIGHT,

> I suggest specifying a NULL value for the first boundary of a RANGE
>   RIGHT partition function.  This NULL boundary serves as the upper
>   boundary of the permanent first partition as well as the lower
>   boundary for the second partition containing data outside the expected
>   range.  No rows are less than NULL so the first partition will always
>   be empty.  It is therefore safe to map the first partition to the
>   previously mentioned dummy filegroup even if you need to house data
>   outside the expected range.  That being said, there is no harm in
>   mapping the first partition to another filegroup other than lack of
>   clarity.